# electron on macOSX - copy files into ~/Library

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I want to build a `electron` app, the idea is simple - user will drag and drop a folder into my app and I will copy that for him under `~/Library/some-folder/`.

The front-end is not a problem, my problem is that I'm not sure what's the best practice, should I just use `fs (file system)` and copy the content of my dropped folder to the location?

Also, how can I be sure that my app has the permission to copy to the `~/Library` folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice (and required for the App Store) is to sandbox your app by putting all the files it needs under its own folder in ~/Library/Containers and only giving it access to that folder, which obviously means you can set the correct permissions. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html) for full details.